# Angular ng-if with filtered result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-if` with filtered result. My code is something like this:

```
<div ng-if="vm.products.length | productFilter">
```

I am trying only display the `div` if the filtered product is not empty. I could create a function and achieve the desired result. But I would prefer to use the filter.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a function in your controller using $filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do the following. You can wrap the result of `filter` in brackets.

```
<div ng-if="(vm.products| productFilter).length">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your filter into your controller and filter it in the JavaScript:

```
function YourController ($filter) {
   var productFilter = $filter.get('productFilter');

   vm.products = productFilter(products);
}
```